# Access the Body of Request (text/xml)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest, content-type

How can I access the body (`content`) of an `Request` which its `content-type` is `text/xml` on the serverside in ASP .NET (C#). (Not the response content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
_XmlData = enc.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class, specifically the [HttpRequst.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) property.